# ¿Que es un virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

Tengo una idea de que es un Virtualbox, pero me gustaría que alguien me explicara un poco mas acerca de lo que es, para que sirve, sus ventajas, desventajas, entre otro tipo de información complementaria que me ayude a saber que es un Virtualbox. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación, dentro del alcance definido en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Te refieres a Oracle VM VirtualBox, una Virtual Box hecha con puntos de colision en un juego u alguna otra cosa?

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox es un software, puedes ver en wikipedia en español.

Que es y para que sirve:(por las dudas aclaro que no miré el video completo)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wt2SutbC1uo

Creo que tu pregunta se refiere una virtualización:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualizaci%C3%B3n

La ventaja que podría mencionar por mi experiencia (escasa pero experiencia al fin):
Hablando en lenguaje coloquial, es que te permite mantener tu sistema operativo 'limpio'. 
Es decir, si por ejemplo, tienes que desarrollar una aplicación con algún framework de una versión 1.0 y otra aplicación con el mismo framework pero de una versión 3.0, lograr que esas dos versiones del mismo framework coexistan en un mismo sistema operativo sería como mínimo muy complicado. Por lo que lo más recomendable para un caso así es instalar dos maquinas virtuales e instalar todo lo necesario en cada una, dejando limpio tu sistema operativo.
 Otra ventaja es que esas maquinas virtuales se pueden compartir ya que se pueden descargar como imágenes ISO.
Una desventaja sería que al hacer correr o 'encender' esas máquinas virtuales están consumiendo recursos de tu máquina 'real' o del sistema anfitrión.

Answer (score 1):

En pocas palabras es un Software (simulador)(maquina virtual) creado por Oracle, donde puedes simular maquinas, asignando las caracteristicas deseadas, como lo son la RAM, HDD, numero de Nucleos, adaptadores de red y un largo etc.

Una vez creada la maquina virtual puedes instalar un sistema operativo, ya sea Linux, Windows, Mac y otros no tan conocidos para hacer pruebas en ellos o utilizarlos para ciertas tareas como prueba de software que tu hallas desarrollado, al igual que correr algun programa que solo funcione en cierto sistema.

Por ejemplo, en lo personal soy usuario Mac, y utilizo las maquinas virtuales para usar Linux desde mi mac, windows para crear USB booteables, ejecutar programas exclusivos de windows (juegos). Asi que bien, tendras y podras ejecutar Sistemas Operativos dentro de tu Sistema Operativo.

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) es un software (actualmente de Oracle y gratuito), que te ofrece un entorno de *[virtualización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtualizaci%C3%B3n)*. Hay otras [alternativas](https://www.davescomputers.com/support-seven-alternatives-virtualbox/).

Un escenario típico es: uno instala el software VirtualBox en una máquina Windows (también hay para Linux). En este caso, tu computadora+sistema operativo Windows se conoce como la máquina "host" (anfitrión). Luego instalas o creas una o más "máquinas virtuales".  Estas se conocen como máquinas "guest" (invitados, o visitas), y pueden ser otro sistema operativo (como un Linux) o otras versiones de Windows (incluso la misma versión). Lo interesante es que la máquina "guest" es totalmente simulada ("virtualizada") adentro de la máquina host. El sistema "guest" (Linux, por ejemplo), arranca como si estuviera instalado en un disco real de un sistema real, pero en realidad todo está virtualizado. O sea que uno está corriendo al mismo tiempo un Windows y ("dentro de él") un Linux. Esto es muy útil para probar y usar distintos sistemas operativos sin necesidad de instalarlo en una partición diferente del disco y rebootear el sistema. Por supuesto que esto require bastante memoria, y la eficiencia no será tan buena como en una instalación no virtualizada.

Uno a veces también lo usa para correr un windows dentro de otro (por ejemplo, un Windows XP adentro de un Windows 7), sea para probar o por problemas de compatibilidad o porque uno no quiere "ensuciar" su sistema.

La virtualización también se usa a nivel corportativo-servidor (pero no con Virtualbox, que está orientado a usuarios finales) para proveer [VPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server), una alternativa de hosting que hoy es muy popular.